# How to use distinct in MongoVue?

Tags: mongodb

I need to find out distinct values(for example : CreationDate or SourceSystem) in MongoDB using MongoVUE. FYI, I can only use the trial version of the same.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't do that with MongoVUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using MongoVUE. You can do it through MongoDB shell running a command like this:

```
db.[Collection Name].distinct({Property Name})
ex: db.students.distinct('age')
db.students.distinct('age').length; // gives you the record count
```

I usually find SQL to Mongo Mapping Chart page useful in these case ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart )

Answer (score 0):

From having a quick look, I can't see how you can either, as the "Find" feature forces you to use:

```
db.[collectionName].find({...})
```

so doesn't allow you to do:

```
db.[collectionName].distinct({...})
```

I recommend using the normal command line executable for Mongo instead of MongoVUE, then you can use the commands from the 10Gen documentation:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct